# GreaseMonkey - Firefox Web console not showing all javascript errors

Tags: javascript, firefox, console, greasemonkey, userscripts

The Firefox Web console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>) is not showing all Javascript errors that are reported in the Firefox Error Console. How to change this?

It's annoying because the Firefox Error Console has been deprecated and [needs to be re-enabled explicitely in Firefox configuration.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Error_Console)

Example of errors not showing in the Web console is accessing a property of an undefined object. This kind of exception just kills the Javascript running script and is very annoying to debug if it doesn't appear in the log...

```
var obj = undefined;
obj['whatever'];
```

This will raise an error in the Error Console but not the Web console:

```
/*
Exception: obj is undefined
@Scratchpad/1:11
*/
```

Note that "JS > Errors" is checked in the Web Console and Chrome debugging is ON on the Web console configuration.

**EDIT: This seems to only apply to GreaseMonkey userscripts (and scratchpad also).**

Comment: It looks like strict mode is enabled. Go to `about:config` and check for `javascript.options.strict`. This option switches the engine to strict mode which gives you more errors in the Error Console (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Debugging_JavaScript#Strict_code_checking).

Comment: What FF version are you using ? I get the 'obj is undefined' error in the Web console using Firefox 27 (Aurora).

Comment: Why are you using the scratchpad?

Comment: Works for me in Firefox 25 and Nightly, using `data:text/html,<script>var obj = undefined; obj['whatever'];</script>`. Result is a Web Console log entry like this: `TypeError: obj is undefined @ data:text/html,<script>var%20obj%20=%20undefined;%20obj['whatever'];</script>:1`

Comment: OK, it seems to only apply to GreaseMonkey userscript and the scratchpad was not a good test to check if it was applicable in other contexts. So it's more of a GreaseMonkey-Firefox integration issue.

Comment: To see Greasemonkey errors, open the browser console (Ctrl-Shift-J). Set `devtools.errorconsole.enabled` back to `false`.  The web console is tab-specific -- which excludes much add-on activity.  The browser console catches everything that's catchable.  The Firebug console catches most things still.

Comment: @BrockAdams: Please promote your comment to an answer. The browser console is a good solution.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Answer given by Brock Adams in comment:

> To see Greasemonkey errors, open the browser console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>Shift</kbd> - <kbd>J</kbd>). [...] The web console is tab-specific -- which excludes much add-on activity. The browser console catches everything that's catchable. The Firebug console catches most things still.

Plus Nelson comment:

> This worked for me, but only after enabling "Show Content messages" in the gear menu of the browser console.

Comment: Sadly some `console.log()` outputs from Greasemonkey scripts are still NOT visible in **any** console.  I have an `addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified'` here which runs and alters variables.  I can see the variables change, but the apropriate `console.log()` output is missing from all logs.  Apparently some invocations are silenced in some states, their `console.log()` is lost.  (I did not find a way to reproduce this outside the Intranet here yet, so no demonstration possible, sorry.)

Comment: `devtools.errorconsole.enabled` is `false` at my side.  All logging options I can find are enabled.  However, neither browser console nor web console show any bit from the failing Greasemonkey UserScript.  If the script compiles it works, but if the script has a fatal compile error FF is completely mute, as if the script isn't there at all.

Comment: This no longer works. It looks like the error console has been completely removed. How can I get Greasemonkey errors to show up?

Comment: This solution is about the browser console (Ctrl+Shift+J), not the error console.

Comment: This worked for me, but only after enabling "Show Content messages" in the gear menu of the browser console.

Comment: @KrisWebDev Please add the note from Nelson to your answer. Otherwise it would not work.